# Put object request is falling using aws sdk for iOS when connected to wifi

Tags: ios, file-upload, https, amazon-s3, nsurlerrordomain

Our iOS application is using the aws sdk to upload small picture to s3 using the putObjectRequest endpoint.

Some of our users are affected by a strange issue which is completely preventing them to upload any picture when they are connected to a particular wifi network.
We managed to temporarily fix this but we don't know if there are better solutions so we are still wondering how to get rid of this.

### This is what we know about this issue:

- This issue affects several iOS versions, iOS devices, aws sdk updates and we've been facing this for years.
- This is happening only when the user is connected to wifi, using mobile network is not causing any issues.
- The incriminated wifi ISP is Vodafone Italy but we don't know if there might be others.
  A file with a size less then 15kb is more likely to be uploaded correctly, while a file bigger then 100kb always fails.
- The problem is happening during the upload of the picture data to s3 from the client. To do that we are using the S3PutObjectRequest class.
- The error is returned by the method request:didFailWithError: of the AmazonServiceRequestDelegate protocol, within two seconds after the request is started.
  We managed to record two different error instances happening in this case:

  - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
  - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "request body stream exhausted"

### What we tried to do:

- Update the aws library with the latest version. This didn't solve the issue.
- Use a bigger connectionTimeout value for the upload request. This didn't solve the issue. As I said the error is fired a couple of seconds before starting the request.
- Change the aws endpoint to use http instead of https: http://s3.amazonaws.com. **This solved the issue.**

---

Have you heard about this issue before, maybe related to another wifi ISP?
Does using http to upload expose ourself into a security issue by passing the signing token on plain text?

We are signing each request with a temporary token set in the amz-security-token header as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#UsingTemporarySecurityCredentials

Thanks